# Como enviar JSon para outra activity?

Tags: java, android

Como enviar JSon para outra activity?

```
        public class SolicitaDados extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls){
        return Conexao.postDados(urls[0], parametros);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resultado){

        try {
            JSONObject Dados_Geral = new JSONObject(resultado);

            JSONArray arrayEmpr = Dados_Geral.getJSONArray("empresa");
            JSONArray arrayEsta = Dados_Geral.getJSONArray("estado");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```

Tenho na MainActivity 2 JSONArray-> empresa e estado, agora necessito usar empresa na activity Empresa, e estado na Activity Estado. Como posso enviar estás arrays?

Agradeço a ajuda! Sou iniciante e não estou entendendo muito bem todo o conteúdo de programação Java Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode simplesmente colocar o JSON numa `String` e envia-lo usando o método `putExtras()` desta forma:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DestinoActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("json", jsonobj.toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

Para resgatar novamente a `String` na *activity*, basta você inserir ao `JSONObject` usando o método `getStringExtra()`. Veja como ficaria no seu `onCreate()`:

```
public class DestinoActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_destino);

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(args.getStringExtra("json"));

    }
}
```

Para saber mais detalhes sobre o `Intent`, veja [na documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Comment: Perfeito. Muitíssimo obrigado!!!!